# Regex expression for a rule in yii model validation

Tags: php, regex, yii, pcre

I'm trying to figure out a regex to express this string:

```
 dev_XXX_<name>
```

where XXX is a 3 digit number and name is already expressed with `/[0-9a-zA-Z \- _]/`.

This regular expression will be used as a model validation rule in PHP/YII, so it's a PCRE regular expression.

My non-working solution is this one:

```
/^dev_([0-9]{3})_<([0-9a-zA-Z \- _])>*$/
```

But it seems to not accept the last major sign.

Thank you for any help & explanations!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your asterisk is in the wrong place

```
/^dev_([0-9]{3})_<([0-9a-zA-Z \- _])>*$/
```

should be

```
/^dev_([0-9]{3})_<([0-9a-zA-Z \- _]*)>$/
```

This will mean that your character set `[0-9a-zA-Z \- _]` should match zero or more of those characters